# MS Access VBA FileSystemObject does not accept path with spaces in them

Tags: ms-access, vba

How do I get around the limitation VBA have of not allowing spaces in file path when using the FileSystemObject?

Here is my code:

```
from= "C:\Users\MyAccount\Desktop\a.txt"
to= "C:\Users\MyAccount\Desktop\Folder Name With Spaces\b.txt"
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fso.CopyFile from, to
```

I have already tried the trick with adding " before any spaces, it doesn't work.  The "Bad FileName or Number" error actually pops up.

I have also tried to replace any spaces with %20, which also does not work.

To clarify, I don't know the path beforehand, it is entered by the user.

Comment: There's no restriction around having spaces in filenames or paths, either in VBA or when using the FSO. You must have some other problem. For example I don't think FSO will create a destination folder if it doesn't already exist. Also: you don't need to use Createobject if you **Dim ... As New ...**: your object is created in the Dim statement.

Comment: Yep, you got it.  Turned out I was removing the last char of the user input for for \ but forgot to check the case when there is no \.

Answer (score 1):

There's no restriction around having spaces in filenames or paths, either in VBA or when using the FSO. You must have some other problem.

For example I don't think FSO will create a destination folder if it doesn't already exist.

Also: you don't need to use Createobject if you Dim ... As New ...: your object is created in the Dim statement.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to the same issue:

```
Dim folderPath As String
folderPath = "D:\MyData\BackUp\capdat\City Name"
If Len(Dir$((folderPath & "\OLDData" & Format(Date, "-ddmmyyyy") & ".accdb"))) > 0 Then
    Kill (folderPath & "\OLDData" & Format(Date, "-ddmmyyyy") & ".accdb"
Else
    Do something
End if
```

Answer (score 0):

its a while since I did any VBA but I think you need to enclose your strings in quotes to negate the spaces in the paths, so does this work:

```
fso.CopyFile """" + from + """", """" + to+ """"
```

EDIT:

[This site](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showpost.php?p=1348512&postcount=10) suggested this routine:

Private Function GetQuotedArgument(ByVal argument As String) As String
        Const Quote As String = """"
        Return String.Format("{0}{1}{0}", Quote, argument)
    End Function

giving:

```
fso.CopyFile GetQuotedArgument(from), GetQuotedArgument(to)
```

Failing that you'll have to resort to short forms of the file names...  Microsoft article on doing that [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175512), not sure if it applies to VBA though

Comment: GetQuotedArgument doesn't work because String.Format does not exist in VBA.

Comment: Tim Willian got it, turned out I was removing the last char of the string for \ but forgot to check condition when there is no slash at the end.